# Regex Check Facebook Video URL

Tags: regex

I try to check facebook video url using regex.

this is example Valid fb video URL : 
https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=100000000000000 (VALID)

this is example Valid fb video URL with username :
https://www.facebook.com/{username}/videos/100000000000000

note : {username} can contain any string.
example :
https://www.facebook.com/username1/videos/100000000000000 (VALID)
https://www.facebook.com/username2/videos/100000000000000 (VALID)

But my reqex still wrong if i check fb video url with username.

This is my regex :

```
^http(s)?://(www\.)?facebook.([a-z]+)/(?!(?:video\.php\?v=\d+|usernameFB/videos/\d+)).*$
```

You can run it : 
https://regex101.com/r/dF5iP1/6

Comment: Do you want {username} to match [/]?

Comment: no. {username} is any string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
^(https?://www\.facebook\.com/(?:video\.php\?v=\d+|.*?/videos/\d+))$
```

## Demo

https://regex101.com/r/sC6oR2/3

Comment: how if the last character from  url contain "/" ?
like this "https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10000000/"

Comment: i found it "@^(https?://www\\.facebook\\.com/(?:video\\.php\\?v=\\d+|(.*?/videos/\\d+|.*?/videos/\\d+/)))$@m";

Comment: There's a possible video url alternative who need regex modif: https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=499831560618548
i did a fast modified version https://regex101.com/r/sC6oR2/134

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED October 2018**

Neither of the two existing REGEX proposals worked for me, and there are more visible cases than the ones considered.

Here's **my REGEX Proposal**:

```
^(?:(?:https?:)?\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\/[a-z\.]+\/videos\/(?:[a-z0-9\.]+\/)?([0-9]+)\/?(?:\?.*)?$
```

```
^(?:(?:https?:)?\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\/videos\/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\/)?([0-9]+)
```

*I ignored `video.php`, I think it's old enough to safely ignore it.*

**Matches:**

https://www.facebook.com/aguardos.nocturnos/videos/vb.1614866072064590/1828228624061666/?type=2&theater
https://www.facebook.com/aguardos.nocturnos/videos/vb.1614866072064590/1828228624061666?type=2&theater
https://www.facebook.com/aguardos.nocturnos/videos/1828228624061666/
https://www.facebook.com/latavernadelssomnis/videos/1609038972452561/?hc_ref=NEWSFEED
//www.facebook.com/aguardos.nocturnos/videos/1828228624061666/
https://facebook.com/aguardos.nocturnos/videos/1828228624061666/
http://www.facebook.com/aguardos.nocturnos/videos/1828228624061666/
www.facebook.com/aguardos.nocturnos/videos/18282286240612666/
facebook.com/aguardos.nocturnos/videos/18282286240612666/
https://www.facebook.com/aguardos.nocturnos/videos/1828228624061666
https://www.facebook.com/WEAU13News/videos/588612391555522/UzpfSTEzMzAzMDk4NjM6MTAyMTMxMjMzNDE3ODE0MTI/

*I do not own nor I have watched any of the videos. I just picked random ones that were on my facebook feed.*

**Groups**

1. Video ID.

**Gotchas**

One of the most common Facebook video formats is more complex than I'd like it to be and matching every case perfectly with REGEX would probably lead to a very messy query.

https://www.facebook.com/RolandGarros/videos/10155404760334920/FOO (valid)

https://www.facebook.com/RolandGarros/videos/FOO/10155404760334920 (valid)

https://www.facebook.com/RolandGarros/videos/10155404760334920/FOO/FOO (invalid)

The way this one seems to work is by retrieving the numeric value in the first or second part after `videos/`.

https://www.facebook.com/RolandGarros/videos/10155361533554920/1015536153355492134

What about this one where two valid numeric values are involved? It seems like the second one is the one that will prevail.

For this reason the REGEX solution above was softened<sup>1</sup> to match only the beginning of the Facebook URL, up to the video group that we're looking for. Considering that your goal's probably to extract the video ID, rather than verify the URL, I think that's a valid trade-off. At the end of the day, you'll be checking the video either way (either through API or scrapping) to extract the video information since an ID doesn't mean that the video exists or it's public.

<sup>1</sup> Not just softened, but also improved to match the test case format.

**Test**

You can easily test it yourself @ [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Updated for a-z and A-Z
`^(?:(?:https?:)?\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\/videos\/(?:[a-z0-9\.]+\/)?([0-9]+)\/?(?:\?.*)?$`

Answer (score 1):

This is a little different than Pedro's, but it works well.

```
^http(?:s)?://(?:www\.)?facebook.(?:[a-z]+)/((?:video\.php\?v=\d+|username\d/videos/\d+)).*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/nV4rI3/1

Answer (score 1):

Latest:

```
/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www.|web.|m.)?(facebook|fb).(com|watch)\/(?:video.php\?v=\d+|(\S+)|photo.php\?v=\d+|\?v=\d+)|\S+\/videos\/((\S+)\/(\d+)|(\d+))\/?/
```

Answer (score 1):

That will help you
[regexr.com/4tdur](https://regexr.com/4tdur)

you can use like this

```
const myURL =  "https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=100000000000000";
const res = /^https?:\/\/www\.facebook\.com.*\/(video(s)?|watch|story)(\.php?|\/).+$/gm.test(myURL);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Could you please add a comment to explain how this relates to the question, parsing facebook URLs?

Comment: the link have regexr that check if url if facebook video

Answer (score -1):

The Facebook Video URLs nowadays are of the formats as following:-

https://www.facebook.com/NowThisPolitics/videos/968643940204333/
 https://www.facebook.com/chandni.nathani2/videos/10158204539960536/UzpfSTEwMDAwMTc3MzU1MjI2NzoyNzMxNDUyMTYzNTkwNTQy/

Also, since the `facebook` could be replaced by `fb`, I created this regex:

```
/(?:https?:\/{2})?(?:w{3}\.)?(facebook|fb).com\/.*\/videos\/.*/
```