# Excel / XLS - filter data (with regex) and transform it to new cells (Possible with openrefine?)

Tags: excel, csv, sorting, excel-formula, openrefine

I'm stuck with a problem. I'm not an Excel expert.

I found some threads how to use regex in Excel, like:

- [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

But I don't know how to filter several things out of a data source to a newly created column.

Example:

The data source is mostly HTML-sourcecode in one cell.

I built RegEx for matching links (ahref), youtube, facebook videos, infogr.am links and other stuff.

I want to:

Extract/filter the links from the html to a new column, like:

New column "Links"

```
 <a href="url">link text</a> \n
 <a href="url">link text</a> \n
```

(every filtered link a new line in the cell)

Optional: paste another column next to it, which counts the paragraphs/links (counting the lines).

Then the video links (one line per filtered data again) + optional counting column.

And so on.

I found Openrefine. Which seems very nice and professional. But I didn't find out how to do it there.

I don't have to work with Excel, later the results can be converted to *.csv - it will be data for the database.

Though I think Excel is nice for the first steps, as the optional counting paragraph thing.

Comment: Trying to parse HTML with Regexes is... how to say that ? a very  hot topic on StackOverflow :D (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). But in OpenRefine, you can create a new column based on the column that contains your HTML cells using this GREL formula : forEach(value.parseHtml().select('a'), e, e.join('\n'))

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah,got it about parsing HTML with RegEx.

When i create a new column based on column links and put your code in:

[error: join expects an array and a string] numerous times. I don't really know why.

Maybe:

I realised that it's not the entire html. It's just the html code with:
<div>.... </div>
<p> </p> 
 + Text, Image Src, Links and Stuff.

Could that be the error that <html> </html> Tags are missing?

Also have to check how to convert my RegEx into GREL.

But thanks anyway, i will look more into OpenRefine. Should be good for that.

Comment: Made a mistake in my formula. Could you edit your question and post an example of html ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xW6E1jzs

Matched links with this:

(?i)<a\shref=\"([^>]+)\">

Pictures with this:

\<img.+src\=(?:\"|\')(.+?)(?:\"|\')(?:.+?)\>

And so on.

Thanks again. I'm really stuck and i think i accepted a task, which isn't really for me.

Could give me an advice how to form regex to GREL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new column from the HTML with each links in the same cell, separated by a newline:

```
forEach(value.parseHtml().select('a'), e, e).join('\n')
```

You should see something like this:

[image]

Or if you want only the text of the links:

```
forEach(value.parseHtml().select('a'), e, e.htmlText()).join('\n')
```

Or if you want only the urls:

```
forEach(value.parseHtml().select('a'), e, e.htmlAttr('href')).join('\n')
```

To create a new column from the HTML that count the number of links:

```
forEach(value.parseHtml().select('a'), e, e).length()
```

There is no picture or video in your sample, so I can't show you how to find them. To extract the infogr.am links :

```
forEach(value.parseHtml().select('iframe[src*=infogr.am]'), e, e.htmlAttr('src')).join('\n')
```

OpenRefine uses [JSoup selectors](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html), that are very similar to CSS selectors. Simply use the right selector inside the `.select()` function.

Comment: Thanks again!

It works great and i think i understand it a bit. In all cases i just need the link/image/video-URL.

Filtered <img> .... <src> with that:

forEach(value.parseHtml().select('img'), e, e.htmlAttr('src')).join('\n')

Works nice.

Image Count with that:

forEach(value.parseHtml().select('umg'), e, e.htmlAttr('src')).length()

The Link Filter of course also contains the image and videos, but that's fine the link counter is to be expected to count all clickable links.

Comment: Looks like this in HTML:

https://pastebin.com/FikRy1nS

My RegEx:

\<script id="infogram.+src\=(?:\"|\')(.+?)(?:\"|\')(?:.+?)\>

But that selects a bit too much:

http://e.infogr.am/420ff00a-fbf0-485e-849a-66479dd1c189?src=embed

would be what i need.

Video:

Really complex, because there are countless ways to link Facebook or Youtube Video

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860182/regex-check-facebook-video-url

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377262/regex-for-youtube-url

And not all videos are linked, some are embedded. So i can't just select from link list